# Spark SQL - How to SUM values over date range linked to a especific date

Tags: date, apache-spark-sql, sum, date-range

I need to do a sum of the values in the last 30 days (exclusive) relative to that date, with every product in every store.
Assuming all months with 30 days:

```
date|store|product|values
2020-06-30|Store1|Product1|1
2020-07-02|Store1|Product2|4
2020-07-01|Store2|Product1|3
2020-07-18|Store1|Product1|4
2020-07-18|Store1|Product2|2
2020-07-18|Store2|Product1|2
2020-07-30|Store1|Product1|1
2020-08-01|Store1|Product1|1
2020-08-01|Store1|Product2|1
2020-08-01|Store2|Product1|6
```

In the lines of day 2020-08-01, sum the values of (2020-08-20 - 30 days) to 2020-08-19 and put it in the 2020-08-20 line, like this:
(first line doesn't include '2020-06-30' because is more than 30 days ago and '2020-08-01' because is the same day, and this goes on...)

```
date|store|product|sum_values_over_last_30_days_to_this_date
2020-08-01|Store1|Product1|5
2020-08-01|Store1|Product2|6
2020-08-01|Store2|Product1|5
....
```

Tried this below and nothing too:

```
spark.sql("""
SELECT 
a.date,
a.store,
a.product,
SUM(a.values) OVER (PARTITION BY a.product,a.store ORDER BY a.date BETWEEN a.date - INTERVAL '1' DAY AND a.date - INTERVAL '30' DAY) AS sum
FROM table a
""").show()
```

Anybody can help me?

Comment: Where is a.values column ? in your  table? Please give us table correctly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try `self-join` rather than window function, maybe this kind of `join` will work -

```
SELECT 
    a.date, 
    a.store,
    a.product,
    SUM(IFNULL(b.value,0))
FROM
    table a
LEFT JOIN
    (
        SELECT
            a.date, 
            a.store,
            a.product,
            a.value
        FROM
            table  a
    )b
ON
    a.store = b.store
AND
    a.product = b.product
AND
    a.date > b.date - INTERVAL 30 DAYS
AND a.date <= b.date
GROUP BY 
    1,2,3
```

Make sure to sum the value from the inner query, to have the sum up until this daye.

Comment: Thanks @Assaf!! Just the dates on JOIN i had to modify to "AND    (a.date - INTERVAL '30' DAY) <= b.date
AND     a.date > b.date"
and attention: There **must** be ONE line for each date,store,product (my dimensions).
Or just SUM values with group by date,store,product before the join.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my trial with the sampel dataframe.

```
+----------+------+--------+------+
|      date| store| product|values|
+----------+------+--------+------+
|2020-08-10|Store1|Product1|     1|
|2020-08-11|Store1|Product1|     1|
|2020-08-12|Store1|Product1|     1|
|2020-08-13|Store1|Product2|     1|
|2020-08-14|Store1|Product2|     1|
|2020-08-15|Store1|Product2|     1|
|2020-08-16|Store1|Product1|     1|
|2020-08-17|Store1|Product1|     1|
|2020-08-18|Store1|Product1|     1|
|2020-08-19|Store1|Product2|     1|
|2020-08-20|Store1|Product2|     1|
|2020-08-21|Store1|Product2|     1|
|2020-08-22|Store1|Product1|     1|
|2020-08-21|Store1|Product1|     1|
|2020-08-22|Store1|Product1|     1|
|2020-08-20|Store1|Product2|     1|
|2020-08-21|Store1|Product2|     1|
|2020-08-22|Store1|Product2|     1|
+----------+------+--------+------+

df.withColumn("date", to_date($"date"))
  .createOrReplaceTempView("table")

spark.sql("""
    SELECT
        date,
        store,
        product,
        COALESCE(SUM(values) OVER (PARTITION BY 1 ORDER BY date RANGE BETWEEN 3 PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING), 0) as sum
    FROM table
""").show()

+----------+------+--------+---+
|      date| store| product|sum|
+----------+------+--------+---+
|2020-08-10|Store1|Product1|0.0|
|2020-08-11|Store1|Product1|1.0|
|2020-08-12|Store1|Product1|2.0|
|2020-08-13|Store1|Product2|3.0|
|2020-08-14|Store1|Product2|3.0|
|2020-08-15|Store1|Product2|3.0|
|2020-08-16|Store1|Product1|3.0|
|2020-08-17|Store1|Product1|3.0|
|2020-08-18|Store1|Product1|3.0|
|2020-08-19|Store1|Product2|3.0|
|2020-08-20|Store1|Product2|3.0|
|2020-08-20|Store1|Product2|3.0|
|2020-08-21|Store1|Product2|4.0|
|2020-08-21|Store1|Product1|4.0|
|2020-08-21|Store1|Product2|4.0|
|2020-08-22|Store1|Product1|6.0|
|2020-08-22|Store1|Product1|6.0|
|2020-08-22|Store1|Product2|6.0|
+----------+------+--------+---+
```